# Openshift multipart image upload returns 502 Proxy Error

Tags: node.js, express, openshift, multer

I am trying to upload image to Openshift using my Node.js backend. The code works correctly in my local server but sending request to Openshift using Postman causes it to wait for few seconds followed by:

```
502 Proxy error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request 
Reason: 
        Error reading from remote server
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR});
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');

app.post('/auth/profilePic',upload.single('profilepic'),function(req,res,next){
    userController.setProfilePic(req,res);

 });
```

Controllers/user.js:

```
var dirName = process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR;
exports.setProfilePic = function(req,res){
   User.findOne({email: req.headers['x-auth-email']}, function (err, user) {
           if (err) {
               res.send(err);
           }
           if (!user) {
               res.status(404).send({message: 'user not found'});
           }
           else if (user.password == req.decodedToken) {
               fs.rename(dirName + req.file.filename,dirName + user._id, function(err){
                   if (err) {
                       res.send(err);
                   }
                   else {
                       user.profilePicture = dirName + user._id;
                       user.save();
                       res.status(200).send({message:'save OK'});
                   }
               });
           }
       });
   };
```

Comment: does other endpoint work fine on openshift? ex. a simple GET request to some endpoint

Comment: Yes. I have 4-5 other endpoints that are working as expected.

Comment: I tried debugging by putting console.log statements and surprisingly, it started working as expected! 
I have removed those statements and now the code is still working!! I don't understand what kind of bugs Openshift has.